# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOne' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOne' of undefined at Function.ADataMembers.associate. Here is ADataMember.js

```
'use strict'

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
var ADataMembers = sequelize.define('data_members', {
    code: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    names: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    first_last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    second_last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    career_id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    phone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    image_url: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
    },
    name_status: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    has_key: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    },
    birthday: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
})

ADataMembers.associate = function(models) {
    models.ADataMembers.hasOne(models.ACareers)
    models.ADataMembers.hasOne(models.AMemberStatus)
    models.ADataMembers.belongsTo(models.ADataArea, {
        foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false
        }
    })
}

return ADataMembers
}
```

Here is my index.js

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const basename = path.basename(__filename)
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env]
const db = {}

let sequelize
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config)
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config)
}

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js')
    })
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file))
        db[model.name] = model
})

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db)
    }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

I was following this example https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/articles/express/#introduction
but something went wrong. I'll be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining it with a different name.

Change this:

```js
var ADataMembers = sequelize.define('data_members', {
//                                     ^ this is the problem
```

To this:

```js
var ADataMembers = sequelize.define('ADataMembers', {
```